# How to use hypothesis testing to compare groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hypothesis-test

I have a data frame with name, type, and Turnover per game. A sample of that df is given below.

```
Name    Type    Turnover per game
kevin   A       5
duke    B       10
jonas   A       12
angly   A       2
anjelo  B       10
wily    A       4
nick    A       8
```

What I want to do is **implement a hypothesis test to check, Type A players have average less turnovers than Type B players.**.

What I tried :

Firstly, group by Type:

```
df.groupby('Type').mean()
```

But I don't know how to implement a hypothesis test to check the above condition.

Comment: what does this line means?
(s['American'], s['Europe'])

Comment: after groupby need to implement hypothesis testing to check the above condition

Comment: NO. it just returns type A mean. What I want to do is implement the hypothesis test in python to check the above-highlighted state

Comment: I check and honestly no idea, never working with hypothesis test

Comment: Me too mate. This is my very first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hypothesis testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) can be done with [ttest_ind](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

data = {'Name': ['kevin', 'duke', 'jonas', 'angly', 'anjelo', 'wily', 'nick'],
        'Type': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'],
        'Turnover': [5, 10, 12, 2, 10, 4, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

t,p = stats.ttest_ind(df.Turnover[df.Type.eq('A')], df.Turnover[df.Type.eq('B')], 
                      equal_var=False, alternative='less')

if p < 0.05:
    print('Type A players have average less turnovers than Type B players')
else:
    print('Null hypothesis (equal means) cannot be rejected.')
```

In your example, the null hypothesis that type `A` and `B` players have equal turnovers will be reject and the alternative hypothesis that type `A` players have average less turnovers than type `B` player will be accepted. See the section *Interpretation* in the above linked Wikepedia article for details.

Comment: Thanks. How to define the null and alternative hypotheses from the above question? Can you kindly mention them?

Comment: H0 = type A and B players have equal turnovers; H1 = type A players have less turnovers than type B player (for one-sided test with alternative 'less')

Comment: Hi it hard to install scipy 1.6.0. Is there any other method to do this? for alternative parameter requires 1.6.0 version. Lower versions  don't contain alternative parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The hypothesis test you have mentioned, if I understand correctly, looks straingtforward.

Get the turnover mean by grouping by 'Type'

```
df_group_by_type = df.groupby('Type')['Turnover per game'].apply(np.mean)
df_group_by_type

Type
A    6.2 
B    10.0
```

and then just check the required condition

```
df_group_by_type['A'] < df_group_by_type['B']
True
```